# Leaving punctuations untouched during Caesar Cipher in python

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I read multiple related threads about how to solve the same problem, but I couldn't apply the solutions to my code.

Also, the code is supposed receive a path to a text file which must contain text composed of only English letters and punctuation symbols and a destination file for encrypted data.

Any suggestions?

```
    def check_alpha(m_string):
        list_wanted = ['!', '?', '.', ',', ' ']
        for letter in m_string:
            if not (letter in list_wanted or letter.isalpha()):
                 return False

            return True and any(letter.isalpha() for letter in m_string)

    while True:
       string = input("Enter the text to be encrypted: ")
       if check_alpha(string):
        break
       else:
          print("Please enter a valid text: ")
       continue
    while True:  #  Validating input key
        key = input("Enter the key: ")
        try:
            key = int(key)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid key: ")
            continue
        break
    
    
    def caesarcipher(string, key):   #  Caesar Cipher
        encrypted_string = []
        new_key = key % 26
        for letter in string:
            encrypted_string.append(getnewletter(letter, new_key))
        return ''.join(encrypted_string)
    
    
    def getnewletter(letter, key):
        new_letter = ord(letter) + key
        return chr(new_letter) if new_letter <= 122 else chr(96 + new_letter % 122)
    
    
    with open('Caesar.txt', 'a') as the_file:  # Writing to a text file
        the_file.write(caesarcipher(string, key))
    
    print(caesarcipher(string, key))
    print('Your text has been encrypted via Caesar-Cipher, the result is in Caesar.txt')
```

Comment: First of all, you should fix your code formatting. Secondly, if you want to keep punctuation as is, you simply need to check if the letter you are trying to encrypt is a punctuation symbol or not. If it is, simply add it to the ciphertext unchanged. You already seem to implement something similar in `check_alpha`, so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The check_alpha part of the code was suggested to me recently, therefore I didn't know the same concept could be used to solve the new problem as well. I'll work on it now. Thank you

Comment: Check out the built-in [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) too

Comment: Also `True and condition` and just `condition` have identical truth values.

Comment: @norok2 that is my doing this stupid mistake so I take it on myself. Either way it's useless `True` statement which does not break the funcitonality but yeah, you have the point.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Alex P you can simple handle all punctuation separately with a `if` condition:

```
def caesarcipher(string, key):   #  Caesar Cipher
        encrypted_string = []
        new_key = key % 26
        for letter in string:
            if letter in ['!', '?', '.', ',', ' ']:
                encrypted_string.append(letter)
            else:
                encrypted_string.append(getnewletter(letter, new_key))
        return ''.join(encrypted_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can make another function which can relate to `check_alpha()` function.

EDIT: I hope I understand your problem correctly. If not then let me know.

```
import pathlib

def load_file(file_path)
   from pathlib import Path
   
   if not Path(file_path).exist():
      return False
   
   with open(file_path, 'r') as fin:
      for line in fin.readlines():
           if not check_alpha(line.strip('\n')):
              return False

   return fin.read() -> this will create '\n' at every end of the line! keep that in mind

def check_aplha(m_string).... -> keep the original

while True:
   fin = input("Enter file path with text selected for encryption: ")
   uncoded = load_file(fin)
      if uncoded: -> everything which is not None, Empty, False or 0 is True
         break
      else:
         print("Please enter a valid file with only valid letters/punctuations.\n")
         continue

while True:
   fout = input ("Enter file path for output file: ")   

   try:
      if not Path(fout.parent).exists():
         Path(fout.parent).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            break
      else:
         break
   except NotADirectoryError as err:
      print(f'Error {err} has occured. Probably wrong disk selection.')
```

In this way exactly you can do it for encrypted data. I guess all rules apply either on encrypted either on decrypted data.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts very much, however I think I had a wrong understanding of the problem for which I apologize. The requirement is: the code must accept two file paths: src and dst. The first path must point to an existing file, which must contain the required text to be encrypted. The second path is for the destination file, the file which you must use to write the result to @JohnyCapo

Comment: @Juj take a look at my Edit, this could work...

Comment: Hey @JohnyCapo , I already have my final code which I believe works properly, I could show you the code if you want, otherwise once again I thank you very much for your efforts and hope you have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

A simple example of the Ceaser Cipher tailed for your need

```
def encrypt(text,s):
  result = ""
  # transverse the plain text
  for i in range(len(text)):
    char = text[i]
    # Encrypt uppercase characters in plain text
    if is_a_letter(char):
    
      if (char.isupper()):
        result += chr((ord(char) + s-65) % 26 + 65)
        # Encrypt lowercase characters in plain text
      else:
        result += chr((ord(char) + s - 97) % 26 + 97)
    else:
      result += char
  return result
#check the above function
text = "CEASER!CIPHER.DEMO"
s = 4 # the length of the shift 
my_list = ['!', '?', '.', ',', ' ']

# check if the character is one of the above list
def is_a_letter(text):
  for x in range(0,len(my_list)):
    if text == my_list[x]:
      return False
  return True

print("Plain Text : " + text)
print("Shift pattern : " + str(s))
print("Cipher: " + encrypt(text,s))
```